# For a given Location, I only want to connect to one specific WiFi connection. How?

Tags: macos, wifi

When I'm at a specific location, I want my MBP to connect to only one specific WiFi connection available.  Too many times it "automatically" connects to garbage WiFi signals like "xfinitywifi" or "CableWifi" that are nearby, and I always have to manually set the connection to the one I really want to use.  Is there a way to limit a macos WiFi connection to a specific WiFi signal?

Comment: Are you not willing to 'forget' wifi like xfinitywifi?  I've done this and I never auto-connect to that one.  If I want to connect in the future I have to manually reconnect (which isn't a problem for me because I don't want to connect to it, ever).

Comment: I'll add it as an answer and you can accept if you like it.

Comment: Well if you go to `System Preferences > Network > WI-FI (left) > Advanced (button on the right) > WI-FI (fist tab)` , you can drag Wi-Fi networks to preferred order. So if you're near networks A and B and B is above A, B is the one it'll connect to. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Joonas has the right idea. Also I would uncheck the box for "Remember network this computer has joined". This will prevent it from remembering these random unsecured networks and automatically joining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](http://www.imore.com/how-set-wi-fi-your-mac):
Here's how to forget a wifi location so that you don't auto-connect to it when in range.

1. Click the Wi-Fi icon toward the upper right of your screen in the menu bar. It looks like a pizza slice.
2. Click on Open Network Preferences.
   [image]
3. Click the Advanced button.
4. Click the Wi-Fi tab.[image]
5. Select the network(s) you'd like your Mac to forget.
6. Click on the minus (-) button.[image]
7. Click on the OK button.
8. Click on the Apply button.[image]